# Virtual Machine Resources

Tags: linux, virtualization

I'm running a process which is latency sensitive and running it on a shared virtual box for costs reasons.

How can I analyze how busy (utilization) on this box ? In particular, I'm concerned about large context switching times between my processses and other users processes which will affect the response time of my application.

The top command only shows my processes...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following command to count the number of context switches since boot time.

cat /proc/stat |grep ctxt